# Is it possible to recover/acquire schema of FlatBuffers binary file

Tags: file-format

Without having access to the schema file, is it possible to recover the schema of a binary `FlatBuffers` file by examining the file? Also, some of those files contain encrypted scalars. If you can actually recover the schema, will encrypted scalars hinder the effort of recovering the schema?

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is no... unless you have fine grained control the application that uses it, so that you can map out individual fields. But then if you have access to the application, you have access to the schema anyway.

Comment: @MegaTonnage Thanks for the information. The app is available. Can it be dissembled to figure out the schema? No source code for the app is available. It is in native android.

Comment: The schema is compiled and included in the binary as a header, so I would say yes, most likely

Comment: @MegaTonnage Can you point me in the right direction to acquire it please. Any guides/tutorials are appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you decompile the app, there will be a class that defines the schema... it is generated with the `flatc` command. I'm just going by the usage docs here: https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/